# How to make a script with apt-get commands?

Tags: shell, tcl, apt-get

I'm doing a script which installs a tcl plugin.

But this tcl plugin require some additional tcl/tk libraries, so I was thinking about putting an APT-GET install command for installing these libraries.

Is there a way to use the APT-GET install command in a script (it can be Shell script, Perl or even Tcl)?

Comment: Why would it be any different than any other terminal command? Assuming the shell script is run in a terminal (meaning an install prompt is visible), then putting `apt-get install <package>` should work fine. I just tested it with a shell script installing gparted.

Comment: While this is fine if you're the only one who will run these scripts, it's not a good practice to run apt-get from shell scripts. It needs to be run under a root account (or use sudo) and makes the script dependent on your distribution (e.g. you won't be able to run it on Fedora).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of how to do it with one line and assumes you are running the script with `sudo` or have appropriate privilege.

```
apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq --yes --force-yes install tcl
```

`-qq` suppresses output unless an error occurs

`--yes` answers the prompt 'Do you want to continue? [Y/n]'

`--force-yes` installs packages that come from a private repository

Consider running `apt-get update &` earlier in the script.  Check or wait for the job to finish before using `apt-get install`

You can list multiple packages on one line.  Packages are installed in the order they are listed.

Comment: `-qq` implies `--yes`