# Bash: Automatic reaction on press y or n

Tags: bash, shell, apt-get

I'm starting to learn  shell scripting.
I using Ubuntu and the APT and for example I will install apache with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Eveythink work's but their prompt a message with

> "Press y/n to install ..."

And I want that my script press automatic yes for me.

Thank's for help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update -y`

Comment: See: [How to make a script with apt-get commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33848391/3776858)

Comment: See: `man apt-get`

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
```

You can look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

For any command that don't have a `-y` option as `apt-get`, you can use `yes` command :

```
yes | yourcmd
```

To give other input :

```
yes nothanks | yourcmd
```

Or with a delay between inputs :

```
while true; do echo "y"; sleep 1;done | yourcmd
```